# Get page from database with PHP, MySQL and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite, structure, directory

I am currently building my own (very small) CMS. I am using PHP/MySQL and mod_rewrite for dynamically fetching the page requests from the database.

So far I had a plain structure like:

```
domain.com/page
```

This all works perfectly fine. But now I want to add "folders" or "categories".

The table has the needed fields (simplified):

```
id, name, pid (parent id)
```

I also worked out how to build the navigational structure from the database, but what I did not figure out so far is, how to get the requested page from the database by using mod_rewrite and PHP.

- How do I get the requested URLs like

  ```
  domain.com/folder1/page
  ```

  or more complex

  ```
  domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/.../folderN/page
  ```
- How can I differ the document "page" in "folder1" from the document "page" in "folderN"?
- How do I treat not existing folders, like "folder2" in the example above?

Uhm, honestly I am a little bit helpless at the moment and hope someone here is willing to help me. :-)

Of course I googled and searched in stackoverflow, but I did not find any specific help. Links to tutorials are also welcome.

Thanks in advance & best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that Apache can't talk to MySQL so it doesn't know which folders do or do not exist.

The way most CMSs (like wordpress) solve this is to redirect every request that is not for an existing file or directory to an entry script of the CMS.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? index.php [L]
```

and then in the index.php check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to see what the request was for and handle accordingly.

```
$parts = explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    // see what the part is for, and if it does not exist
    // if you find that the request does not exist, send a 404 back to the browser
    // header($_SERVER['HTTP_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
}
```